# Calling included remote functions and variables

Tags: php, file, include

I'm trying to include a remote file from one of LAN pcs using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [allow_url_fopen = On](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) and [allow_url_include = On](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include).

One local PC (let's say pc2), I have remote.php, which contains:

```
<?php
echo $var_on_pc1; // this doesn't output
$remote_var = 'Var on pc2';

function square($num){ 
    return $num * $num;
}    
?>
```

In my PC (let's say pc1), I have test.php, which consists of this:

```
<?php
$var_on_pc1 = 'Var on pc1'; 

include "http://pc2/path/to/remote.php";

echo $remote_var; // this doesn't output
echo square(4); // this got error
?>
```

When I run the script test.php, i got the error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: square() in
>   path/to/test.php on line 7.

What happened? I thought I could call the included functions and variables and vice versa?
If I cannot implement this, what is the best way?

I have no security concern because I use this locally for temporary development.

Comment: including remote files isn't a good idea. If you need remote functionality then you could create a web service on the remote box

Comment: I just need to include remote files as working like local file includes.

Comment: Yeah I know that you want to do that. But that's a security and design  issue

Comment: As I said, I have no security issue.

Comment: then you have still a design issue ;) If you are working in  a local LAN, why not mounting the remote files using: nfs,sshfs,ftps or samba?

Comment: The better answer here is a robust *deploy mechanism* that deploys that shared file to all servers automatically. Look into Ansible, Puppet or Chef.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I'm on Windows. What do you mean design issue?

Comment: I confirm with deceze. The design issue is, that you'll have to make sure, that files are present on the server which needs to excute them. While using remote file includes will fix the problem temporarly, a deployment strategy is what you really need

Answer (score 4):

Type `http://pc2/path/to/remote.php` into your browser and see what you get. PHP gets exactly the same.

If the PHP file is being processed by the web server at `pc2`, you likely get zilch in that file, because the code as been processed. You'd need to configure the other server to not process the PHP file and serve its raw source code instead.

This is not a good idea overall.

Comment: The remote.php has no output. It just defines some functions and variables. It was executed according to my trace. How can I configure to serve it as raw source code.

Comment: Depends on what server you have running there. You need to configure it to treat *.php files as pure text instead of PHP executables. Again, since this is a bad idea, I'm not going to handhold you how to do that.

Comment: From your answers and comments, I got some understanding on this issue. Thank you.